Adjust the date as working date | Oracle |
I was reviewing several articles on Stack Overflow and came across a query that worked as expected. However, I need to make some modifications to tailor it to my specific requirements.
I need to ensure that only Monday to Friday dates are considered. For any dates falling on Saturday or Sunday, applying a positive or negative offset should return the nearest working day (Monday to Friday).
I just used 0 and -1 ....but it could be any number ( negative or positive )
-ve ... 0 .... +ve  

Tabular format for better understanding



Case
Input Date
Day of the Week
Operation
Expected Output Date
Expected Day (Working Day)




Case 1
13-APR-2024
Saturday
0 or -1
12-APR-2024
Friday


Case 2
13-OCT-2024
Sunday
0 or -1
11-OCT-2024
Friday


Case 3
08-OCT-2024
Tuesday
+4 or +5
11-OCT-2024
Friday


Case 4
15-OCT-2024
Tuesday
+2
17-OCT-2024
Thursday


Case 5
15-OCT-2024
Tuesday
-1
14-OCT-2024
Monday


Case 6
15-OCT-2024
Tuesday
-2
11-OCT-2024
Friday


Case 7
15-OCT-2024
Tuesday
-3
11-OCT-2024
Friday



Explanation of cases
Case 1 :  When date is 13-APR-2024 which is (SATURDAY) doing 0 or -1 it should give me FRIDAY date 12-APR-2024 which is working date.
Case 2 : When date is 13-OCT-2024 which is (SUNDAY) doing 0 or -1 it should give me FRIDAY date 11-OCT-2024 which is working date.
Case 3 : When date is 08-OCT-2024 which is (TUESDAY) doing +4 or +5 (SATURDAY 12-OCT-2024 / SUNDAY 13-OCT-2024) it should give me FRIDAY date 11-OCT-2024 which is working date.
Below is table
Table :
CREATE TABLE table_name (dt, days) AS
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 0, -3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 2.5, -3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 2, -1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 3, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 2, 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 5.5, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 5.5, 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 0.2, 5 FROM DUAL;

Query :
SELECT dt,
       days,
       -- Start of Week
       TRUNC(dt, 'IW')
       -- Add Full Business Weeks (multiples of 5 days)
       + FLOOR((LEAST(dt - TRUNC(dt, 'IW'), 5) + days)/5)
         * INTERVAL '7' DAY
       -- Add Part Business Weeks  
       + LEAST(dt - TRUNC(dt, 'IW'), 5) + days
       - FLOOR((LEAST(dt - TRUNC(dt, 'IW'), 5) + days)/5) * 5
         AS offset_day
FROM   table_name;

From above table the expected day need to be printed...

@MT0  : Could you help me with above question.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You appear to be adding/subtracting a number of days (not working days) and then if the resulting date is a weekend then subtract days so that the result is a Friday.
SELECT dt,
       days,
       dt + days - GREATEST(TRUNC(dt + days) - (TRUNC(dt + days, 'IW') + 4), 0)
         AS offset_day
FROM   table_name;

Then for your sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (dt, days) AS
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 0,   -3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 2.5, -3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 2,   -1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 3,    2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 2,    7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 5.5,  0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 5.5,  7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 0.2,  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-04-13',   0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-04-13',  -1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-10-13',   0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-10-13',  -1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-10-08',   4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-10-08',   5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-10-15',   2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-10-15',  -1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-10-15',  -2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-10-15',  -3 FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



DT
DAYS
OFFSET_DAY




2024-10-07 00:00:00 (MON)
-3
2024-10-04 00:00:00 (FRI)


2024-10-09 12:00:00 (WED)
-3
2024-10-04 12:00:00 (FRI)


2024-10-09 00:00:00 (WED)
-1
2024-10-08 00:00:00 (TUE)


2024-10-10 00:00:00 (THU)
2
2024-10-11 00:00:00 (FRI)


2024-10-09 00:00:00 (WED)
7
2024-10-16 00:00:00 (WED)


2024-10-12 12:00:00 (SAT)
0
2024-10-11 12:00:00 (FRI)


2024-10-12 12:00:00 (SAT)
7
2024-10-18 12:00:00 (FRI)


2024-10-07 04:48:00 (MON)
5
2024-10-11 04:48:00 (FRI)


2024-04-13 00:00:00 (SAT)
0
2024-04-12 00:00:00 (FRI)


2024-04-13 00:00:00 (SAT)
-1
2024-04-12 00:00:00 (FRI)


2024-10-13 00:00:00 (SUN)
0
2024-10-11 00:00:00 (FRI)


2024-10-13 00:00:00 (SUN)
-1
2024-10-11 00:00:00 (FRI)


2024-10-08 00:00:00 (TUE)
4
2024-10-11 00:00:00 (FRI)


2024-10-08 00:00:00 (TUE)
5
2024-10-11 00:00:00 (FRI)


2024-10-15 00:00:00 (TUE)
2
2024-10-17 00:00:00 (THU)


2024-10-15 00:00:00 (TUE)
-1
2024-10-14 00:00:00 (MON)


2024-10-15 00:00:00 (TUE)
-2
2024-10-11 00:00:00 (FRI)


2024-10-15 00:00:00 (TUE)
-3
2024-10-11 00:00:00 (FRI)



fiddle

Half working
select mydate,current_day,days,working_date,to_char(working_date,'DAY') from (SELECT
    mydate,
    current_day,
    days,
    CASE
        -- Adjust for current day being Saturday or Sunday
        WHEN TRIM(current_day) = 'SATURDAY' and (days=0 or days=-1) THEN mydate - 1
        WHEN TRIM(current_day) = 'SUNDAY'   and (days=0 or days=-1)  THEN mydate - 2
        ELSE
            CASE 
                WHEN days > 0 AND TRIM(TO_CHAR(mydate + days, 'DAY')) = 'SUNDAY' THEN (mydate + days) - 2
                WHEN days > 0 AND TRIM(TO_CHAR(mydate + days, 'DAY')) = 'SATURDAY' THEN (mydate + days) - 1
                ELSE mydate + days
            END
    END AS working_date
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            mydate,
            TRIM(TO_CHAR(mydate, 'DAY')) AS current_day,
            days
        FROM
            table_name
    )
);


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
